# My subTopics doesn't show up when it's clicked with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subTopics").hide();
    $("#mainTopics").click(function () {
        $("#subTopics").show("slow");
        
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}


#main-menu {
    position: relative;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}


#subTopics {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#subTopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subTopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}


#column1, #column2, #column3, .columns {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}


#main-menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="mainTopics">Topics</a>
                    <div id="subTopics">
                        <div id="column1" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example7</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example8</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example9</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example10</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="column2" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example11</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example13</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example14</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example15</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example16</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example17</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example18</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example19</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example20</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="column3" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example21</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example22</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example23</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Markets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi When i clicked on my element subtopics it doesn't show up i don't know if i have done some wrong code and when i refresh my page it's just happened appear and disappear onetime like blinking.Can any professional web development help me out about this? thank you very much. (I'm sorry for my poor english)
****All i want is i want my subTopics show up or dropdown by clicking not by hover****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>

</header>
<nav>
    <div id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="" id="mainTopics">Topics</a>
                <div id="subTopics" class="classSubTopics">
                    <div id="column1" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example4</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example5</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example7</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example8</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example10</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="column2" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example11</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example12</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example13</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example14</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example15</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example16</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example17</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example18</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example19</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example20</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div id="column3" class="columns">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">example21</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example22</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">example23</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Markets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#subTopics {
position: absolute;
display: none;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#mainTopics").click(function (event) {
    $(".classSubTopics").hide();
    event.preventDefault()
    $("#subTopics").show("slow");
});

});
```

Comment: This is works very much.Would you mind to help me a little bit more? I also want the subTopics hide again once i clicked to other menus or where there is space. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Add a class for all the submenus then do `$('.subMenus').hide()` before you show the current on

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work even without `jQuery`. you can do this with `css` only.

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
}

li, a{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: black;
}


#main-menu {
    position: relative;
}

#main-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main-menu a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}


#subTopics {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

#subTopics ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#subTopics li {
    display: block;
}

#subTopics a {
    text-align: left;
}


#column1, #column2, #column3, .columns {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 125px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}


#main-menu li:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#main-menu li:hover #subTopics {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>

    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="main-menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Logo</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="" id="mainTopics">Topics</a>
                    <div id="subTopics">
                        <div id="column1" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example6</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example7</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example8</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example9</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example10</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="column2" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example11</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example12</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example13</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example14</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example15</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example16</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example17</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example18</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example19</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example20</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div id="column3" class="columns">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">example21</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example22</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">example23</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Markets</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: Hi Zuber,I actually want to access subTopics by clicking only.by the way thanks.